# How to use f-Literal with PartiQL in AWS and boto3 and a Condition on the sort key

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, partiql

This is my current Code

```
table_name = 'TableName'
pk = "CID-73665"
Condition = "begins_with(sk,'CUS#')"

# get item 
stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE pk=? and {Condition}"
pmt =[{
    "S": pk
    },
    {
     "S": sk   
    }]

resp = dynamodb_client.execute_statement(
    Statement=stmt , Parameters= pmt
 )

pp.pprint(resp['Items'])
```

But i get this error message:

```
NameError: name 'sk' is not defined
```

Anyone has an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 'sk' is not defined. You try like this

```
table_name = "TableName"
pk = "CID-73665"
sk = "CUS#"

# get item
stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE pk=? and begins_with('sk', ?)"
pmt = [{"S": pk}, {"S": sk}]

resp = dynamodb_client.execute_statement(Statement=stmt, Parameters=pmt)

pp.pprint(resp["Items"])
```

Comment: Works. Thx Borislav Stoilov